# Which model should I use to fit my data?

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, discrete-data, model

Here is a problem I'm struggling with for some days now on !

Here is the kind of data I have

```
dependent.variable = c(0,1/3,1/3,1,0,1/3,2/3,1,0,1/3,1/3,1,1/3,1/3,1/3,1,0,2/3,2/3,1)
independent.variable.1 = rep(c(10,20,50,100),times=5)
independent.variable.2 = rep(c('proust','sante','cheers','nazdrovia'),each=5)
```

I want to know which independent variables (and which interactions) affect the dependent variable.

My dependent variable is a proportion of true over n possible things. In my example n=3, so that there is either 0/3, 1/3, 2/3 or 3/3 which are true and the rest is false. In other cases my dependent variable might be booloean or take many possible states (n=1000). I want to take into account that my dependent variable is ordinal.

The independent variables might or might not be ordinal. They are everytime discrete. I also want to consider possible interactions between independent variables.

**Which stats should I use ?**

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Logistic regression?